# Get child by ID

Tags: javascript

```
<div onclick="test(this)">
    Test
    <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

I want to change the style of the child div when the parent div is clicked.  How do I reference it?  I would like to be able to reference it by ID as the HTML in the parent div could change and the child won't be the first child etc.

```
function test(el){
  el.childNode["child"].style.display = "none";
}
```

Something like that. Where I can reference the child node by ID and set the style of it?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Point taken with IDs needing to be unique. So let me revise my question a little: I would hate to have to create unique IDs for every element that gets added to the page. The parent div is added dynamically, (sort of like a page notes system). And then there is this child div. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
el.getElementsByName("options").item(0).style.display = "block";
```

If I replace `el` with `document`, it works fine, but it doesn't to every "options" child div on the page. Whereas, I want to be able to click the parent div, and have the child div do something (like go away for example).

If I have to dynamically create a million (exaggerated) div IDs, I will, but I would rather not. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I can't do document.getElementById("child") since there may be multiple "child" id's on the page.

Comment: you can't have multiple ids the same on the page... - see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Comment: You can't have elements with the same ID on the same page. If it's a css thing try using classes.

Comment: Okay, can I do this by Name then?  For example, in my function using: el.getElementByName or something.  I just need to reference parent>child.  And the child needs to be specific.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In modern browsers (IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari) you can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
function test(el){
  el.querySelector("#child").style.display = "none";
}
```

For older browsers (<=IE7), you would have to use some sort of library, such as [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or a framework, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), to work with selectors.

As mentioned, IDs are supposed to be unique within a document, so it's easiest to just use `document.getElementById("child")`.

Comment: Brilliant!  Resolved by using: el.querySelector('div[name="options"]').style.display = "block";

Nice to learn new functions.

Answer (score 18):

This works well:

```
function test(el){
  el.childNodes.item("child").style.display = "none";
}
```

If the argument of item() function is an integer, the function will treat it as an index. If the argument is a string, then the function searches for name or ID of element.

Comment: According to [w3shools.com][http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nodelist_item.asp] item only supports numerical(index) arguments

Comment: it supports a string as well.

Comment: hm.. don't trust this.  Asked for 'TXT_div_8' and got 'TXT_div_7' - so it's not matching the id from the text passed to item in chrome.

Answer (score 11):

If the child is always going to be a specific tag then you could do it like this

```
function test(el)
{
 var children = el.getElementsByTagName('div');// any tag could be used here..

  for(var i = 0; i< children.length;i++)
  {
    if (children[i].getAttribute('id') == 'child') // any attribute could be used here
    {
     // do what ever you want with the element..  
     // children[i] holds the element at the moment..

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById('child')` should return you the correct element - remember that id's need to be unique across a document to make it valid anyway.

edit : see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp) - ids MUST be unique.

edit edit : alternate way to solve the problem :

```
<div onclick="test('child1')">
    Test
    <div id="child1">child</div>
</div>
```

then you just need the test() function to look up the element by id that you passed in.

Comment: Hey, sorry.  I added a comment on my post.  I need it to be specific to the parent div though, not to the entire document. I hear what you are saying with the ID's....but for argument sakes, is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: edited answer to add an alternative way to do this. hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to find specific child DOM element** use method **querySelectorAll**

`var $form = document.getElementById("contactFrm");`

in $form variable we can search which child element we want :)

[image]

For more details about how to use **querySelectorAll** [check this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)