# target a div in another div javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to target a div inside another div with javascript (no Jquery, trying to learn raw Javascript first). say I've got a set of 3 divs, called "outerSquare1", "outerSquare2", etc  and each has a div inside called "innerSquare" (not numbered).

How can I target the inner square of a particular div at a later point via Javascript. I want to do something like this, but obviously not working.

```
outerSquare2.innerSquare.style.width="100px";
```

Or this

```
foo = outerSquare3.getElementById("innerSquare");
foo.style.width="100px";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmperkins74/r866bnwu/6/)

Comment: `document.getElementById()` will give you any element with that id. No matter outer or inner etc. Just use the proper id.

Comment: The first fundamental point is - do _not_ have more than 1 element with the same `id`. It is technically not legal HTML and methods such as `getElementById` don't work properly with it. You would be better off making `innerSquare` a class instead

Comment: `#id`s should be unique. If you want different nodes to have the same "id," then use a class.

Comment: another post that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899072/javascript-get-child-by-id

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.class` instead of `#id` when you need to group some similar HTML elements. And when you use it, you can use the `node#querySelector(selector)` method which returns a nested node, that matches the selector. There is some example, how you can do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/r866bnwu/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [childNodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) property that return a list of the children of a DOM element. Here is an example. Hope this help.

```
    <html>
    <style>
        #outerDiv{
            height:150px;
            width:150px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }

        .innerDiv{
            position:relative;
            height:20px;
            width:50px;
            top:60px;
            margin:auto;
            background-color:white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function writeInner(){
            document.getElementById('outerDiv').childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'Hi there';
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">

        </div>

    </div>
    <button id="me" onClick="writeInner()">Click me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```