# Use a selector to get a child element?

Tags: javascript, html

I can use the following to get an element:

```
document.getElementById('the-container');
```

Is there a way to get a child (not necessarily an immediate child) of this component.

```
<div id="the-container">
    <div class="whatever">
       <form>
           .....
```

I'd like to get the form element, without adding an id/class or targeting it via the `form` tag (might be other forms on page).

No jquery but happy for HTML5.

Comment: All children are immediate children. Don't confuse other kinds of descendant with children.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript get child by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899072/javascript-get-child-by-id)

Google knows a lot. Especially simple stuff like this.

Comment: does your form have a name?

Comment: @Pete — I'd hope not. This is the 21st century.

Comment: @Quentin And why is that? It's still a [valid attribute for a form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) and would allow you to just get it using `document.forms['name-of-form']`

Comment: @Pete — It was superseded by `id` over two decades ago. `id` does everything that `name` does, plus a bunch of stuff `name` doesn't do, and is two bytes shorter.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with ES6.

Comment: @Quentin but the OP says "without adding an id" so if there is a name, then you may as well use it, obviously it would be preferable to use id

Answer (score 1):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is a property of Element objects and takes a selector as its first argument.

```
document.getElementById('the-container').querySelector("form");
```

You could also use it directly on the whole document with a more elaborate selector:

```
document.querySelector('#the-container form')
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be more efficient to just add an id to the form?

Comment: Yes, it would be more efficient.