# Getting a child by using its id which build at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and its tbody is adding rows at runtime with icons(delete and update), 
Now I want when I click on delete icon, I can get the innerHTML by using the id not an index.
I can use this to get the innerHTML by using index
event.target.parentNode.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].innerHTML;

but what I want is to get the child by using it child id which created at runtime not in HTML and build before??

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript get child by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899072/javascript-get-child-by-id)

Comment: In general, `id`s in a table showing tabular data are more or less useless, they're just eating memory. There are many ways (indexing being one of the best) to refer the elements in the table, and the DOM traversing can also be much more efficient than in your example. If we assume you want the first cell of the row where the clicked element is placed, you can use `e.target.closest('tr').firstElementChild`. Maybe you should show the table structure you're working with, we might get a good method to refer the target without ids.

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple;
assign a unique ID to the HTML element and then grab it with the document.getElementById('id').innerHTML

Here is an example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the color of this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()"><p>Try it</p></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For further assistance please visit
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: If we have a dynamic table where the rows are removed and added all the time, getting the correct ID becomes more or less impossible at some point.

Comment: Then assign the index number of the loop to the id.

Comment: How about a very general usecase, when you've only a single delegated event listener for the table, which could even be used for multiple tables ..? Like I said in my comment on the question's comment thread, ids are not usefull in the context of the tables.

Comment: yes that is what I mean, is there a way of catching a current field of a row by id, even if I put an id, all the rows will have the same id??

Comment: Yes, that's right. We also can use a map() if there is an Array of elements.

Comment: No, you can't use same ID for every element in HTML, ID must be unique otherwise it will give an error.

Comment: @Nesreenmhd Please reconsider what you really need. You're creating a superfluous and very error-prone layer on your your table with ids. Every cell on the table already has an "id", tables and tbodys have `rows` collections, rows have `cells` collection, rows have `rowIndex`, cells have `cellIndex`, and all these are live, always up to date, unlike the id layer you're planning.